# Tags não entendo muito

Tags: html, css, html-tags

Boa noite gostaria de saber tudo sobre Tags, não só as básicas como
`<html></br><h1>` etc... mas tipo o que cada uma faz por exemplo
não consigo descobrir alguns desses elementos.

```
dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50; - cor do fundo
    color: white; - cor da letra
    padding: 16px; não sei
    font-size: 16px; tamanho da font
    border: none; não sei
    cursor: pointer; não sei
position: relative; não sei
    display: inline-block; não sei
```

Comment: Você provavelmente deveria começar estudando por algum livro sobre o assunto. Você que as tags do HTML e as propriedades do CSS são coisas diferentes, né? Na sua pergunta dá a entender que você não saberia diferenciar muito bem.

Comment: Além das dicas abaixo, segue um guia bem completo sobre CSS. [CSS Reference](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/)

Answer (score 1):

Seria muito evazivo te explicar uma a uma. O melhor a se fazer é você procurar alguns tutoriais de `CSS` e `HTML`. Isso, hoje em dia, tem bastante conteúdo na internet. Mas vou tentar explicar algumas delas:

**padding**:

Ele coloca uma especie de margem para dentro entre o conteúdo e o box. Uma imagem que pode te ajudar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem, vemos o conteúdo **Hello Word** que está dentro de uma `div` (só pra exemplificar) em amarelo. O padding faz essa margem entre o ponto de dentro do box até o conteúdo (hello world)

**font-size**:

Como o próprio nome propõe, ele é o tamanho da fonte, ou seja, o tamanho do texto.

**border**:

Serve para você configurar as bordas do elemento, como por exemplo, o tipo de borda (linha, traços, etc.), cor da borda, etc.

**cursor**:

Com o próprio diz, ele mexe com o cursor do mouse, possibilitando por exemplo, ao passar o mouse em um link o mouse fique a "mãozinha" ou o cursor de ponteiro, entre várias outras opções.

**position**:

Ele mexe com a posição de um elemento da tela. Por exemplo, é possível criar uma div e com o position mandar ela ficar no centro da tela.

**display**:

Como o exemplo que você citou, o `inline-block` ele funciona para deixar elementos em linha (um ao lado do outro) mas com o estilo de bloco. Existe por exemplo somente o `block` que deixa os elementos um abaixo do outro.

Dê uma pesquisada sobre css, como os links abaixo:

http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/joe/cssjoe1.php

https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Antes de começar o desenvolvimento com HTML5 e CSS3 é bom ter uma noção básica geral sobre o ambiente de desenvolvimento web.

1 - Existe uma diferença entre tags do HTML e comandos de estilização do CSS. 
Tags são as que você citou: `<html>,</br>,<h1>`, etc. Agora o código que você vai ver abaixo é um código css com um conjunto de comandos que visão estilizar  os elementos criados por essas tags.

2 - É bom você meter a cara para aprender, cair em cima. Aqui em baixo vou deixar o link de alguns sites que possuem um bom conteúdo para que você possa usar de aprendizado.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/ 
Udacity: https://br.udacity.com/course/intro-to-html-and-css--ud304/

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: /* #4CAF50; - cor do fundo */
    color: white; - /* cor da letra */
    padding: 16px; /* Padding é uma maneira de você aumentar o tamanho de um elemento com espaço "vazio" */
    font-size: 16px; /* tamanho da font */
    border: none; /* Border é uma borda para o elemento em questão, isso faz com que o elemento não tenha borda */
    cursor: pointer; /* Faz com que o cursor do mouse tenha um estilo estilo especifico */
    position: relative; /* Torna a posição do elemento relativo ao elemento pai dele na hierarquia. */
    display: inline-block; /* Demonstra o comportamento do elemento no seu display, se você substituir o valor "inline-block" por "none" o elemento desaparecerá, por exemplo. */
}
```